# Single input dual output simulation help

Tags: power, dc, buck, boost

[image: psim circuit]Ive been using PSIM and there is a problem with the circle mosfet wont turn on. Ive the correct duty cycle and input voltage is higher than the threshold. Can someone simulate it on another simulator or see my anything wrong?
[image: Schematic]

[image: my circuit]
[image: gate drive]

Comment: I don't see your actual simulation schematic.  Without that it's going to be difficult to help.

Comment: Ok there is my PSIM circuit.

Comment: Which MOSFET model are you using?  What does your gate drive signal look like?

Comment: N-channel mosfet

Comment: Ive added a picture of the control

Comment: Normally it is the 1st switch that needs a boost voltage  >> 4.2V to switch V6 to 0 and not V1 with circle. . so what is the Vgs/Vt ratio for that FET?  >> 2.5??

Comment: V1 has duty cycle of 0.54

Comment: `V1`, as shown in your picture, is showing switching behaviour, and it looks as intended, because it's switching from below zero (diode clamp), to the input voltage level, 4.2 V. Is it supposed to be different? What did you expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

Your Signal Source goes from -3V to +3V because you have specified the DC offset 0V. You must specify DC offset to 3V and it should work ok.

Comment: Ok just tried that, the result is the same :/

Comment: Could it be that your signal source is not connected to the gate? (I cant see a red line between)

Comment: Its connected straight onto the gate. I draw a line but that didnt change anything :/